# Linking google merchant account doesn't work even in supported country

Tags: google-chrome-extension, android-pay, country, merchant-account

I am trying to link my Google Merchant account with my Chrome extension on the dashboard following [this guide](http://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap) and even though it suppose to be supported I am getting this message:

*The country in which your Google Wallet account (info@wips.com) is registered is not supported at this time.*

I am registered from the Czech republic and here it is clear the it suppose to be supported:
https://support.google.com/wallet/business/table/3539140?hl=en&ref_topic=4490611

I have succesfully create my Google Merchant account, so I have the Merchant ID, the seller identifier and the Seller secret.

Can you tell me if I am doing something wrong? Or all the changes that happened yesterday are still taking place?

Thank you very much.
Lukas Jan Marek
Wips.com

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are planning to sign up as a merchant for Chrome Web Store Payments which uses the Wallet for digital goods API. The merchant eligibility page you point to is for the Google Play In-App Billing API which has a wider country coverage.

The Czech Republic is not yet supported by Chrome Web Store Payments. Here is the current merchant country availability list for the Wallet for digital goods API:

http://developer.chrome.com/webstore/pricing

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that the Czech republic is not in that list but there is also this senctence:   Buyers in unsupported regions might be able to purchase apps, but they can't pay in their local currency and might have to pay international transaction fees.          And I don't care if I pay in CZK, I still would prefer the USD