# Mobile Chrome Apps payments API

Tags: google-play, google-chrome-app, android-pay, chrome-web-store, cordova-chrome-app

I'm working on publishing my [Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inker-preview/lpfjgigabnjiapappcjdflkdladakjcl) to Google Play using the **Chrome Apps for Mobile tools**.

As Mihai Ionescu [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22368595/4137472), there are two Google Wallet Merchant APIs: **Google Wallet for Digital Goods API** (used for Chrome Web Store apps) and **Google Play In-app Billing API** (used for Android apps). As far as I'm located in **Belarus**, Play API is supported for my country, but Digital Goods is not, though the [Supported Locations table](https://support.google.com/payments/merchant/table/3539140?hl=en&ref_topic=4490611) doesn't mention any API differences.

Mobile Chrome Apps Payment Plug-in [ReadMe](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-google-payments/blob/master/README.md) says:

> This plugin allows you to sell digital and virtual goods within your app. It is built on the **Android In-App Billing API** and the iOS In-App Purchase API. It provides a JavaScript interface similar to the **Chrome Apps Google Wallet for Digital Goods API**, so that you can use the **same API in both a desktop and mobile** Chrome App.

### Questions

- What **exact API** (Google Play or Digital Goods) is used for mobile Chrome Apps and can I really use **one merchant API** for both mobile and desktop versions?
- If different APIs are used, is there any way for a **desktop** Chrome app **to check** that a user has **purchased the mobile** version via Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

For mobile, you will use Google Play In-app Billing API, as the item will ultimately end up on the Google Play Store. Regardless of the API, you will only need to create a single Google Wallet Merchant account to sell your goods, thus using a single Merchant Id.

Unfortunately, there is no way to verify a user's purchases within the app on different platforms (web vs mobile).

Comment: I have a Google Wallet Merchant account, and when I try to link it through the Developer Dashboard I get a message "Your country Belarus is unsupported for this merchant". This [table](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/pricing#seller) shows the limited number of supported regions. How do I link my Merchant account to Chrome Web Store?